# .NET MAUI `Button.OnClicked` Event Does Not Fire When Clicked / Tapped

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

After adding a `Clicked` event handler in the code behind, and adding it to my `Button` in XAML, the `HandleClicked` event handler never fires when tapping the button.

What have I done wrong to cause the `Button.Clicked` event not to fire?

##### MainPage.xaml

```xml
<Button x:Name="AddButton"
  Clicked="HandleClicked"
  Text="Add"
  HorizontalOptions="Start"
  VerticalOptions="End"
  WidthRequest="100">
  <Button.GestureRecognizers>
    <PointerGestureRecognizer PointerEntered="PointerGestureRecognizer_PointerEntered" />
  </Button.GestureRecognizers>
</Button>
```

##### MainPage.xaml.cs

```cs
async void HandleClicked(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var toast = CommunityToolkit.Maui.Alerts.Toast.Make("Add has been clicked");
  await toast.Show();
}
```

#### Steps To Reproduce

1. Run the project on an Android device/emulator
2. Expand the expander at the bottom
3. Try to click on either button
4. No toast is fired

#### Link to public reproduction project repository

https://github.com/glenn2223/Community-Toolkit-Mail-Android-Expander-Issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you've aded a `GestureRecognizer` to your `Button` which is overriding the `Clicked` action.

When you remove the `GestureRecognizer`, the `Clicked` event fires:

```xml
  <Button x:Name="AddButton"
          Clicked="AddClicked"
          Text="Add"
          HorizontalOptions="Start"
          VerticalOptions="End"
          WidthRequest="100">
  </Button>
```

I do not know if this behavior is intended by the .NET MAUI engineering team. I recommend opening this Issue on the [.NET MAUI GitHub Repo](https://github.com/dotnet/maui).

Comment: Pointer gesture recognition is only supported on iPadOS, Mac Catalyst, and Windows. You could refer to [Recognize a pointer gesture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/pointer)

Comment: Thanks @LiqunShen-MSFT. Should PointerGestureRecogizer override the Button.Clicked event? I assume it should not. This is a bit of a code smell.

Comment: @BrandonMinnick - Can't have gesture(s) and button click at same time.